# Menu contribution not triggering with Eclipse Mars 4.5

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-mars

My menu contributions for application using RCP Luna 4.4.2 used to work fine, but a recent migration to Eclipse 4.5 makes me think they might not have been correctly implemented in the first place. The code in the dynamic menu handler is like:

```java
@AboutToShow
void aboutToShow(List<MMenuElement> items, ...) {
    ....
    MDirectMenuItem item = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createDirectMenuItem();
    item.setContributionURI("bundleclass://blablabla/x.y.z.Foobar");
    item.setLabel("labelX");
    items.add(item);
    ...
```

The menu entry shows fine. It is not grayed out. Upon clicking, the @Execute annotated handler method Foobar.execute() is not called with 4.5 (it was called with 4.4.2). Anything wrong or missing in the above code?

Comment: It would be a good idea to write a short answer with the link to the bug and a short summary so that it is clear that this question is resolved (you might even get some votes!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was introduced with the initial release of Mars (version 4.5). It is being discussed at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=469581

A patch has been created, see https://git.eclipse.org/r/50322

It appears the fix will be released in Mars SR1 (4.5.1), scheduled for September 25, 2015.